On the definition of fourier transform and convergence of fourier series
I'm new to Fourier analysis and I have some gaps related to some definitions and notions of convergence. Basically, my main reference is Folland's textbook. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Definition of Fourier transform:

Folland gives a few definitions in different settings of the Fourier transform. First, he gave a definition for functions in $ L^1(T) $:   $$ \hat{f}(k) = \int_T f(x) e^{-2 \pi i kx} $$
(and made a note that $ T $ is measure theoretically identical to a fundamental domain $ Q= [-1/2, 1/2) $ and the latter definition should be taken to be the definition of Fourier transform for periodic functions with fundamental domain $ Q $). Second, he defined it for functions in $ L^1(\mathbb{R}) $ analogously by $$ \hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{-2 \pi i \xi x}. $$A few questions regarding these definitions:
1.a Why would we care to define such an operator on a torus? And, Folland made a choice of a fundamental domain of period 1, while same definition is valid for any other choice. Hence question b:
1.b Should I think of every periodic function as a function on $ T $ and vice versa?
1.c It looks like for $ f $ in $L^1(T)$, $ \hat{f} $ is defined on $\mathbb{Z}$, and for $ f $ in $ L^1(\mathbb{R}) $, $\hat{f}$ is defined on $ \mathbb{R} $. Why is that?

Convergence of Fourier series

Folland, at least in the initial discussion, spoke of convergence in $ L^2 $. Now if $ f $ in $ L^1(T) $, surely we can leverage the $ L^2 $ convergence.
2.a I guess my main concern is the lack of knowledge about convergence, so can anyone please list the main important facts about $ L^1 $, $ L^2 $, and pointwise convergence of the Fourier series of a function on $ T $ and on $ \mathbb{R} $?
2.b In case the answer to 1.b is no, what does it mean to speak of the Fourier series of a periodic function?
Any other general remarks/ important facts for me as someone who's new to the subject are welcome and appreciated.

For 1c, this is unfortunately a bit of an annoying part of Fourier theory when learning it the first time. You're expected to take it on faith that these are the right definitions. The Fourier transform can be defined in multiple ways. The primary ways to arrive at it in a first principles way are via representation theory of certain groups and the spectral theory of certain operators. By restricting to certain regions with appropriate boundary/decay conditions, Fourier series or Fourier transforms emerge.

There are a lot going on here. Let me try to answer a few to begin with. Below are just my own thoughts, mostly set myself free as a semi-lecturer on Folland this semester.
1.a. The reason that $F_1 f(\xi)=\int f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx$ is the "best definition" for Fourier transform instead of $F_2 f(\xi)=\frac1{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int f(x)e^{-ix\xi}dx$ or even worse $F_3 f(\xi)=\int f(x)e^{-ix\xi}dx$ is that $F_1$ is isometry on $L^2$ and also $F_1(f\ast g)=F_1(f)\cdot F_1(g)$ holds, while $F_2$ is isometry on $L^2$ but $F_2(f\ast g)=(2\pi)^\frac n2F_2(f)\cdot F_2(g)$ has a constant. $F_3$ is not even $L^2$ isometric.
If you do the same thing for Fourier transform on torus, the same result is true, the version $F_1$ is $L^2$ isometry and also making the identity $F_1(f\ast g)=F_1(f)\cdot F_1(g)$ true. If you use $\mathbb R/r\mathbb Z$ for $r\neq1$, sure the Fourier transform can still be defined, but either it is not $L^2$ isometry with respect to the standard Lebesgue measure/ counting measure, or the convolution/multiplication identity requires a special constant.
1.b. Yes and no. A better model is to think of $\mathbb T^n$ as a "commutative Lie group", i.e. a group endowed with differential structure. Since there is no need to introduce Lie group, you can think about function on torus as period function on $\mathbb R^n$. But using Lie group, or more generally commutative locally compact Hausdorff (LCH) group, provides generalization to the Fourier transform on $\mathbb R^n$ or torus.
Without mentioning general LCH group (Folland has another whole book discussing "abstract harmonic analysis"), if you think of $f:\mathbb T^n\to\mathbb C$ as 1-period $F:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb C$, then on the next chapter you will see that $\hat F=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^n}\hat f(k)\delta_k$, where $\delta_k$ is the Dirac measure at the point $k\in\mathbb R^n$. In this identification functions on $\mathbb Z^n$ are associated to the weighted sum of Dirac masses.
1.c. Okay we need to talk about LCH group here. In a more abstract setting given a commutative LCH group $G$, its dual group $\hat G$ is the set of all continuous group homomorphism $\chi:G\to\mathbb S^1\subset\mathbb C$. One can check (not easy) that $\hat G$ is also commutative LCH.
On $G$ there is a so-called Haar measure $\mu$, which is a translation invariant Borel regular locally finite measure, unique up to a positive constant. Then for $f\in L^1(G)$ we can define $\hat f\in C^0(\hat G)$ by
$$\hat f(\chi)=\int_Gf(x)\chi(x)d\mu(x).$$
If we consider $G\in\{\mathbb R^n,\mathbb T^n\}$ one can prove that $\hat G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb Z^n$ respectively. The Haar measure is not unique so $F_1,F_2,F_3$ above can all be legitimate definition of Fourier transforms. I want to point out that for $F_2$ the Haar measure should be $d\mu=\frac{dx}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}$ instead of $dx$.

The $L^1$ and $L^2$ should be think of different things.

The $L^1$ serves as the domain of Fourier transform for which $\int f(x)e^{2\pi ix\xi}dx$ is always a classical Lebesgue integral. Without being $L^1$ it is never a Lebesgue integral. Nevertheless you can replace $L^1$ by $M$, the space of finite Borel measures, which serves the same (but slightly more abstract) purpose.
The $L^2$ serves as the principle of isometry. It is the space where $F$ is invertible, and being isometry if you choose the definition well. The issue is that you have to use generalized Riemann integral $\lim_{R\to+\infty}\int_{B(0,R)} f(x)e^{2\pi ix\xi}dx$ to let $\hat f$ makes sense. Logically speaking at this moment you only know $(f\mathbb1_{B(0,R)})^\wedge$ converges in $L^2$. The very difficult Carleson-Hunt theorem tells you (see Sec 6.8) it actually converges almost everywhere.
In general if one just wants to think about the definedness of Fourier transform, $L^1$ or $L^2$ is too small. It is good to consider the space of tempered distributions $S'(\mathbb R^n)$, which is closed under Fourier transform as well.

Nice! Thanks this is helpful! I was hoping to hear more about the Fourier series & its convergence in my second question.
